# Working with different calculation rules in API

Tags: javascript, json, api

Let's say, I have a JS array of object which looks like :

```
var forceData = 
    [ 
       { 
          "mass":5,
          "acceleration":2,
          "ruleToCalculateForce":"mass * acceleration"
       },
       { 
          "mass":5,
          "acceleration":3,
          "ruleToCalculateForce":"mass * acceleration"
       }
    ]
```

> ruleToCalculateForce contains how to calculate **force** using mass
>   and acceleration using Newton's Law which is **Force = mass * acceleration**. The value of this key has same names of the keys associated with it **(mass & acceleration)**.

Now what I want is to calculate the result which multiplies the mass & acceleration based on the rule defined in ruleToCalculateForce.

So, what I am trying to say is that, Is it possible to convert **forceData** array of object to something like this where result (a new key) **can be calculated based on the rule defined in ruleToCalculateForce**:

```
var forceData = 
    [ 
       { 
          "mass":5,
          "acceleration":2,
          "result" : 10,
          "ruleToCalculateForce":"mass * acceleration"
       },
       { 
          "mass":5,
          "acceleration":3,
          "result" : 15,
          "ruleToCalculateForce":"mass * acceleration"
       }
    ]
```

**The forceData rule can be dynamic. Let's say if the force data is something like :**

```
var forceData = 
        [ 
           { 
              "mass":5,
              "acceleration":2,
              "ruleToCalculateForce":"mass + acceleration"
           },
           { 
              "mass":5,
              "acceleration":3,
              "ruleToCalculateForce":"mass + acceleration"
           }
        ]
```

**Then the updated array of object should perform summation instead of multiplication and it should be:**

```
var forceData = 
        [ 
           { 
              "mass":5,
              "acceleration":2,
              "result" : 7,
              "ruleToCalculateForce":"mass + acceleration"
           },
           { 
              "mass":5,
              "acceleration":3,
              "result" : 8,
              "ruleToCalculateForce":"mass + acceleration"
           }
        ]
```

Comment: Usually calculations are made in functions, you call a function with values doing the maths, and then the function returns the calculated value. Functions can't be included in data, but you could build an object with methods doing the maths, and include the method name to the data. Then you can invoke a method like `force = obj[forceData[i].newtonForce](forceData[i].mass, forceData[i].acceleration);`. This way the method is separated from the data, but it includes kinda refrence to the method.

Comment: As people have said, representing functions as strings is highly frowned upon and dangerous. Since this is only math functions, however, maybe you can try the shunting-yard algorithm and a postfix stack evaluation; it might be more trouble than it's worth, though, when simply moving the math into the code instead of the data is the simpler and recommended way.

Comment: You will need a parser, no matter how the data is structured. With the current rule presentation it can be a [math parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) as IceMetalPunk has suggested. Or if you can change the actual rules to rule names, a much more simple collection of parsing methods (as I've suggested in a comment above), or a variant of it as junvar has answered, will do. You could also consider to create your own API for this data structure. See an example of an [API](https://jsfiddle.net/uxhzrb4g/), it also stores the rules using names instead of the actual rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but dangerous and ugly to represent functions as strings. This would typically require the `eval` method or function constructor, both of which are frowned upon.

Instead, since you haven't said storing the functions as a string is a requirement, I would suggest storing functions as functions.

```js
let forceRule1 = obj => obj.mass * obj.acceleration;
let forceRule2 = obj => obj.mass + obj.acceleration;

let forceData = [
  {
    'mass': 5,
    'acceleration': 2,
    'ruleToCalculateForce': forceRule1
  }, {
    'mass': 5,
    'acceleration': 3,
    'ruleToCalculateForce': forceRule2
  }
];

forceData.forEach(obj => obj.resultForce = obj.ruleToCalculateForce(obj));
console.log(forceData);
```

Edit, per comments it's been clarified the rules must be strings. In that case, using eval or function constructors could work:

```js
let forceData = [
  {
    'mass': 5,
    'acceleration': 2,
    'ruleToCalculateForce': 'mass * acceleration'
  },
  {
    'mass': 5,
    'acceleration': 3,
    'ruleToCalculateForce': 'mass + acceleration'
  }
];

forceData.forEach(obj => obj.result = 
    new Function('mass', 'acceleration', `return ${obj.ruleToCalculateForce}`)(obj.mass, obj.acceleration));
console.log(forceData);
```

Comment: This is ofcourse the best way when handling "live" objects in the memory, but somehow it looks like OP's data comes from JSON (quoted property names in the example), and they want to include a way to calculate the value within JSON. I might be wrong with this, though.

Comment: @junvar Can you please, look over the updated question description? I want to calculate them only with rule which has been defined.

Comment: @Shunjid Your problem here is, that you want your serialized data to perform an action, which it is not purposed to.

Answer (score 1):

From the sample data and the description, I guess you only have one type of rule to calculate? Then you can use this:

```
forceData.forEach(element => {
      element["result"] = element.mass * element.acceleration;
    });
```

Also,in this case, you don't need to store the rule in your object.

But if you have any other rules, and provide them here, I can edit the code.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Can you please, look over the updated question description? I want to calculate them only with rule which has been defined. @Fulya D.

Comment: @junvar's answer worked for me but only after changing: obj => obj.result to obj => obj["result']